# Python: < not supported between str and int

Tags: python, syntax

I'm learning Python through *Automate the Boring Stuff* and I'm running into a something I don't quite understand.

I'm trying to create a simple for loop that prints the elements of a list in this format: `W, X, Y, and Z`.

My code looks like the following:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def printSpam(item):
    for i in item:
        if i < len(item)-1:
            print (','.join(str(item[i])))
        else:
            print ("and ".join(str(item[len(item)-1])))
    return

printSpam(spam)
```

I get this error in response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CH4_ListFunction.py", line 11, in <module>
    printSpam(spam)
  File "CH4_ListFunction.py", line 5, in printSpam
    if i < len(item)-1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks for helping a newbie.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how `for ... in ...` works. `i` is already the string from the list, _not_ the index, thus `<` is comparing strings and integers, and `item[i]` does not make sense, either. Also, you are trying to `join` a single item!

Comment: You're basically doing `"s" < 4`. This makes no sense.

Comment: In this case `i` is a string.

You are trying to compare a string to the length of a list.

Comment: Instead of looping, you can use list slices like `item[0:-1]` to get all but the last item, and `item[-1]` to get the last item. Join the first set with `,`, and then connect that with `and` to the last.

Comment: @Barmar: argh, you beat me to it while I was answering :)

Answer (score 5):

Ah, but `for i in array` iterates over each *element*, so `if i < len(item)-1:` is comparing a *string* (the array element `item`) and an integer (`len(item)-1:`).

So, the problem is you misunderstood [how `for` works](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) in Python.

The quick fix?

You can replace your `for` with `for i in range(len(array))`, as `range` works like this:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Thus obtaining:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def printSpam(item):
    for i in range(len(item)):
        if i < len(item)-1:
            print (','.join(str(item[i])))
        else:
            print ("and ".join(str(item[len(item)-1])))
    return

printSpam(spam)
```

The output *probably* won't be what you expect, though, as `'c'.join(array)` uses 'c' as "glue" between the various elements of the array - and what is a string, if not an array of chars?

```
>>> ','.join("bananas")
'b,a,n,a,n,a,s'
```

Thus, the output will be:

```
a,p,p,l,e,s
b,a,n,a,n,a,s
t,o,f,u
cand aand tand s
```

We can do better anyway.

Python supports so-called [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) and negative indexes (that start at the end of the array).

Since

```
>>> spam[0:-1]
['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu']
>>> spam[-1]
'cats'
```

We have that

```
>>> ", ".join(spam[0:-1])
'apples, bananas, tofu'
```

And

```
>>> ", ".join(spam[0:-1]) + " and " + spam[-1]
'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'
```

Therefore, you can write your function as simply

```
def printSpam(item):
    print ", ".join(item[0:-1]) + " and " + item[-1]
```

That's it.
It works.

P.S.: One las thing about Python and array notation:

```
>>> "Python"[::-1]
'nohtyP'
```

Comment: This was literally the most informative explanation on `for` notation in Python that I've read yet and I'm slightly embarrassed that I forgot the `range()` function in my code; CodeAcademy at least taught me that.  I going to go back and try with a different code practice and see if I can make something different this time.  Thanks for your response!